# How do I get combining Unicode to work in Python 2 output?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, output

I have strings that use combining unicode, but can't get Python 2.7 to display them correctly.

For example I have

```
"IJK\818\773LMN"
```

which should display as<sup>*</sup>

```
IJK̲̅LMN
```

but instead appears as

```
JK\818ǻLMN
```

when I

```
from __future__ import (print_function, unicode_literals)
print("IJK\818\773LMN")
```

or

```
from __future__ import (print_function, unicode_literals)
print(unicode("IJK\818\773LMN").encode('utf-8'))
```

I can confirm that device to which I'm printing can display combining unicode correctly.

How do I get combining Unicode to work in Python 2.7 output?

---

OS X: 10.11.1; Homebrew Python 2.7.10_2

<sup>*</sup> *Actually, this may not display correctly in your browser either. It displays correctly in mine though: a bar above and below the 'K'.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the Python notation for **octal** escapes, not Unicode codepoints. If you wanted to include the [U+0332 COMBINING LOW LINE](https://codepoints.net/U+0332) and [U+0305 COMBINING OVERLINE](https://codepoints.net/U+0305) characters for example, you need to use the `\uhhhh` *hex* escape sequence in a Unicode string:

```
>>> print u'IJK\u0332\u0305LMN'
IJK̲̅LMN
```

Here 818 decimal is 0332 hexadecimal, and 773 is 0303 hexadecimal.

You got `\818` instead, because `818` is not a valid octal number (where the digits are in the range 0-7). `\773` in octal translates to [U+01FB LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE AND ACUTE](https://codepoints.net/U+01FB).

Comment: That gives `IJK࠘ݳLMN`.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: yes, I noticed that you used decimal numbers, updated.

Comment: if the codepoints are within range (can be represented using 3 octal numbers) then you can use octal escapes for Unicode e.g., `u'\101' == u'A'`. In this case, both `u'\u0332'` and `u'\u0305'` are outside the range (they require 4 octal digits each).